Previously successful Cloud Run Service & Job deploy process with resource level IAM grants not working anymore for certain projects
I have service account example@project-a.
In project-b, I have cloud run job example, for which I have granted resource level IAM binding:
gcloud run jobs get-iam-policy --project project-b example
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:example@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/run.developer

Prior to August 5, the following worked:
gcloud run jobs update example
    --region=example-region
    --project=project-b
    --image=example-image

Then suddenly, the deploy stopped working. I have not changed anything.
ERROR: (gcloud.run.jobs.update) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'run.jobs.update' denied on resource (or it may not exist). 
This command is authenticated as example@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Same error exists with both gcloud cli v486 and v484.
And also, I have a pre-production project project-c, where an identical deploy still works.
I have verified that seemingly there is no org level or folder level policy, which should interfere deploy.
Also, running gcloud policy-troubleshoot iam --project project-b //run.googleapis.com/projects/project-b/locations/example-region/jobs/example --principal-email=example@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com --permission=run.jobs.update  tells me:
- access: GRANTED
  bindingExplanations:
  - access: GRANTED
    memberships:
      serviceAccount:example@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com:
        membership: MEMBERSHIP_INCLUDED
        relevance: HIGH
    relevance: HIGH
    role: roles/run.developer
    rolePermission: ROLE_PERMISSION_INCLUDED
    rolePermissionRelevance: HIGH

EDIT: as of 9 Aug 06:00 UTC Cloud Run deploys also stopped working in europe region for both preproduction and production projects.

Try removing and re-adding the permissions for your service account on the Cloud Run jobs in 'project-b' to fix any permission issues. Also, check the settings in both projects to check any differences that might be affecting the deployment.

I have done all of that, but 0 differences and 0 findings.
My current main hypothesis is that Google has changed some IAM requirements for these deploys internally just like they recently added IAM requirements on cloud build for cloud function deploys.

This is better for Support. Only changelog is documented happened in July https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes

Already working with Support on this. It just takes time.

When I add project level binding of Cloud Run Developer to example@project-a in project-b, then deploys started working again.
BUT, it should also work with resource level bindings ...
EDIT: This has now been fixed internally by Google. Our setup started working again without any changes.

can you try deploying a new service from scratch? And then remove project level bindings, add them to the service only and re-deploy?
Like this: gcloud run deploy hello  --platform managed  --region europe-west1 --image us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello
It worked for me with Service Only Permissions.
Can you also share the Google Ticket ID with us so that I can reference it?

I only have my own internal support ticket sadly. Nothing public to share atm

As of 2 days ago, our problem has been fixed internally by Google. We did no changes and our setup started working again.
